# What does the Catholic church teach about fate of non-Catholic christians?

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, afterlife

From what I've heard, The Roman Catholic Church claims to be the only representative authority of God on Earth. Does it indeed claim that, and if so what does it say happens to members of non-Catholic churches when they die?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Catholic Church is very explicit in its teachings that ["all salvation comes from Christ the Head through the Church" (CCC 846)](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p123a9p3.htm#846).  The only way to enter the Church and become part of the Body of Christ is through baptism.  Thus, [baptism is necessary for salvation (CCC 1257)](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p2s2c1a1.htm#1257).

This is not meant to be interpreted as only Catholics can attain salvation.  Rather, the Church teaches that "[anyone, even a non-baptized person, with the required intention, can baptize, by using the Trinitarian baptismal formula (CCC 1256)](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p2s2c1a1.htm#1256)."  Thus, anyone baptized with water and "in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit" is part of the Mystical Body of Christ and can attain salvation. To the best of my knowledge, this includes most non-Catholic Christians. (Note there are other forms of baptism recognized, [baptism by blood](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p2s2c1a1.htm#1258) and [baptism by desire](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p2s2c1a1.htm#1260), but those seem out of scope for this question.)

Now Baptism isn't the only requirement for salvation.  One must also die [free from mortal sin (CCC 1033)](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p123a12.htm#1033). For a sin to be mortal, that is to be grave enough to cut us off from the life of God, three conditions must be met: ["Mortal sin is sin whose object is grave matter and which is also committed with full knowledge and deliberate consent." (CCC 1857)](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p3s1c1a8.htm#1857). This full knowledge includes both [knowledge that it is a sin, and that it is a grave matter (CCC 1859)](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p3s1c1a8.htm#1859).  Thus a sinner who through no fault of his own, believes he is not sinning does not commit a mortal sin.

If one does fall into a state of mortal sin, then [normally the sacrament of reconciliation is necessary (CCC 1856)](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p3s1c1a8.htm#1856) to restore or "reconcile" one with God.  However, it is recognized that [a perfect contrition can also attain this forgiveness (CCC 1452)](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p2s2c2a4.htm#1452).

**In conclusion, the Catholic Church teaches that the sacraments of the Church are the surest and easiest way to reach salvation, but it is still possible for other members of the Body of Christ to enter Heaven.**

Comment: @cledoux:: I didn't find from your sources about what catholic church teaches about non-catholic born again christians; I mean are they saved and thus will enter to heaven according to doctrine of catholic church? I would like to get a source for whether non catholic born again christians can attain salvation or not?

Comment: @alvoutila Like many things theological, there isn't an easy yes or no answer. The Catholic Church does not teach a concept of "saved," but that doesn't mean born again Christians are barred from heaven. Those who are part of the Mystical Body of Christ (MBoC) will enter heaven; those who are not will not. So, are born again Christians part of the MBoC? That depends on whether they've been baptized and are free from mortal sin. Baptism joins you with the MBoC, mortal sin cuts you off, and reconciliation restores you to unity with the MBoC.

Comment: If you're interested, [there's an encylical](http://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_29061943_mystici-corporis-christi.html) on the doctrine of the Mystical Body of Christ.